# Pressing both Ctrl keys at the same time is recognized as Ctrl plus Meta

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows

When pressing both <kbd>C</kbd> at the same time, the combination is recognized as <kbd>C-M</kbd> on a Win7 machine and Emacs 24.5.

I've stumbled on this by mistake while pressing <kbd>C-C-SPC</kbd>. While on a Linux machine, this is the same as <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>, on a Windows machine this is recognized as <kbd>C-M-SPC</kbd>. This is very handy, but I'm not able to reproduce the behaviour on Linux.

Any ideas on how I might achieve this on Linux or why is it working only on Windows?

**Update for Windows:**

- If I start emacs with no init files (`emacs -q`), the behavior is still present (i.e. <kbd>C-C-SPC</kbd> is still recognized as <kbd>C-M-SPC</kbd>)
- If I start emacs without the window system (`emacs -nw`) the behavior disappears (i.e <kbd>C-C-SPC</kbd> is recognized as <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>), as expected.

Comment: This is something handled at the OS level rather than by emacs, I believe.

Comment: @Dan, donno, but pressing C-C-DEL outside of emacs, does not invoke the C-M-DEL, so Windows doesn't do this conversion for the ctrl+alt+del, for example.

Comment: Just to check -- it's not the case that in Emacs, one of the control keys is mapped to Meta, is it?

Comment: @zck, no, it is not. I use both Ctrl keys, the left one for navigating, for example, the right one for saving, find-file, etc. While trying to set mark, I accidentally pressed both Ctrls at the same time. Instead of set-mark I got select-word, or something like that. Two seconds later and a C-h k, indeed, C-C-SPC was actually a C-M-SPC and not a C-SPC as I was expecting, and as is the case on Linux.

Comment: Learn something new everyday! I never thought to hold both Control keys down as modifiers. I would have thought that it was redundant. Whoodathunk?

Comment: @Drew, yes, but I still don't know how to replicate that behaviour on Linux.